# Inconsistent button text: skip or next?

Tags: bug, help-improvement

1. Go to the [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) review queue.
2. The buttons in the top-right are "Edit" and "**Skip**".
3. Click the Back button in the browser.
4. Click the Forward button in the browser.
5. The buttons in the top-right are now "Edit" and "**Next**".

This doesn't happen with any of the other review queues. It also happens in some other scenarios (mostly related to using the back button it seems).

Aside from the inconsistency, the word "Next" is rather confusing. Does it mean "Skip this review" or does it mean "This review is done, go to the next"?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the distinction is largely academic; the review has already been committed most of the time you see Next. (Same as with Triage's occasional vote page.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's not how the other queues work; you can go back and do it anyway even if you clicked skip or moved away from the page for another reason. Not sure about triage (I've done 20 today, so I need to wait to test that).

Comment: If you look all the way left, you should also see "This item is no longer reviewable." And at least for the review item I looked at, the review task *actually got invalidated*. Not sure what is going on there behind the scenes, but it seems that the task eventually gets recreated if no action was actually taken. The post I looked at had another H&I review task in the past that had been inexplicably invalidated (probably) the same way. The Edit button seems to just *always* be shown in that queue, regardless of whether the item is completed or not.